# How to make assigning text in a combo box via code automatically select the index?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-xe2, vcl

It's become a hassle to keep writing code for many combo boxes to automatically select the item index of a text value. The problem is that when I assign a text value via code (`ComboBox.Text:= 'Some value';`), the item index isn't automatically selected, even though the exact value is already in the list. So I wind up writing code for every combo box to pick the item index by looking up the value. On other occasions, the value assigned might not already be in the list, in which case further handling will add it. But when that value is in the list, I would expect the item index to automatically be assigned.

I can replicate this behavior by dropping a new combo box, assigning some items, and then assigning a text value to it via code. To verify, I click inside this combo box, and press the Up or Down arrow on the keyboard, and it jumps to the beginning of the list. However, if I drop-down the combo box with this assigned value, it then picks that value in the list and assigns the item index. But I shouldn't have to do that.

Auto complete is enabled, and when the user types such a value manually, it does automatically pick this item index. But assigning a value to the `Text` property which does in fact exist in the list does not pick that corresponding item index.

**Example:**

```
ComboBox.Items.Add('One');
ComboBox.Items.Add('Two');
ComboBox.Items.Add('Three');
ComboBox.Items.Add('Four');
ComboBox.Items.Add('Five');
ComboBox.Text:= 'Five';
```

- User clicks inside combo box control
- User presses Up arrow on keyboard
- First item in list 'One' is selected rather than 'Four'

I would consider this a bug in the VCL, because even if I never need the item index, the user interface still acts up. In my case, I never need to observe the Item Index, because I send the text values as they are to the server as a string. However, because the index is not assigned, the control itself also does not react the way it should, when user navigates by means other than typing or dropping down the box.

What can I do on a global level to propagate to all my combo box controls (within a given form at least) to make assigning text values via code automatically pick that corresponding value in the list?

Comment: `ComboBox.ItemIndex := ComboBox.Items.IndexOf('Five');` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Why would you "keep writing code"? Write it *once* and put it in a function. Aside from that, what value are you using for the `Style` property? If you're using the default `csDropDown`, then you shouldn't really be relying on the index in the first place. The user can type in arbitrary text. So what if it happens to match some text that's in the list? You still have to handle all the other values it could be, too, so why bother handling the indexed values specially at all?

Comment: @KenWhite That's pretty much what I already do. But I have to do it for every combobox, every time I assign something. I'm at a point where it's most ideal to minimize that.

Comment: @RobKennedy As explained, it is the default behavior and properties. I don't rely much on the item index because the text value is read and put into a JSON object to send to the server as a string. But the fact that it doesn't automatically select it in the list when assigning it as so is very annoying. Even if I don't need to ever read the item index, the user interface is still reacting poorly due to this bug (also as explained).

Comment: You haven't identified a "bug". The TComboBox is simply a wrapper around the underlying Windows common control. Rob has made several good points, and I see nothing in your post that addresses them. There is no "global setting" that will change the behavior of all combobox controls. If you don't want the default behavior for the `csDropDown` style, use a different style - if you want the item index to be set automatically, use `csDropDownList`.

Comment: @KenWhite I never asked for such a "global setting", only a solution that would work once for all instances, without having to account for this occasion every time I assign text to them. The user is expected to type new values, and will be added accordingly. But the fact that the Item Index isn't automatically selected (when I have no need for the item index) introduces a problem in the UI, as explained in the question.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to address what you wrote with "What can I do on a global level". There is no "global level setting". If the user is typing new values that didn't exist before, there is no itemindex yet to be set, and you have to do it in code (albeit code written in an interposer class, it's still done in code).

Comment: @KenWhite I wasn't asking how to not do it in code either. I was asking how to write the code once and have that one bit of code propagate to all instances of a combo box, so that I don't have to write the same code many times for each and every combo box I need to assign text to, which Sertac has answered exactly that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an interposer class to change the behavior to something you'll like. E.g.:

```
type
  TComboBox = class(vcl.stdctrls.TComboBox)
  protected
    procedure WMSetText(var Message: TWMSetText); message WM_SETTEXT;
  end;

...


procedure TComboBox.WMSetText(var Message: TWMSetText);
begin
  Perform(CB_SELECTSTRING, WPARAM(-1), Message.Text);
  inherited;
end;
```